# I get an error while using selenium with proxy when trying to load google website, How do I fix this?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import random
import time


class ud:
    def ful(self):
        with open('proxy.txt', 'r') as f:
            num_lines = sum(1 for line in f if line.rstrip())
            if num_lines < 9:
                print("proxy less than 10")
                sys.exit()
            print('Total proxies:', num_lines)
            return num_lines

    def pf(self):
        with open('proxy.txt', 'r') as f:
            numbers = self.ful()
            pxx_l = random.randint(1, numbers)
            f = f.read()
            pxxx = f.split("\n")
            px_n = pxxx[pxx_l]
            pxf = px_n.split()
            pxq = pxf[0]
            return pxq

    def __init__(self):
        proxyy = self.pf()
        print(proxyy)
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxyy)
        chrome_options.add_argument('--no-first-run --no-service-autorun --password-store=basic')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
        time.sleep(10)
        self.driver.get('https://google.com/')
        time.sleep(3)
        self.driver.get('https://bing.com')


dorker = ud()
```

[Error from google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqO5z.png)

I get the following error when i used selenium with proxy but no issues with other sites like bing , netflix.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED
  (Session info: chrome=102.0.5005.63)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x0043D953+2414931]
    Ordinal0 [0x003CF5E1+1963489]
    Ordinal0 [0x002BC6B8+837304]
    Ordinal0 [0x002B8E18+822808]
    Ordinal0 [0x002ADE5D+777821]
    Ordinal0 [0x002AEA3B+780859]
    Ordinal0 [0x002AE06A+778346]
    Ordinal0 [0x002AD646+775750]
    Ordinal0 [0x002AC565+771429]
    Ordinal0 [0x002ACA3D+772669]
    Ordinal0 [0x002BDEA4+843428]
    Ordinal0 [0x00314EBD+1199805]
    Ordinal0 [0x0030449C+1131676]
    Ordinal0 [0x00314812+1198098]
    Ordinal0 [0x003042B6+1131190]
    Ordinal0 [0x002DE860+976992]
    Ordinal0 [0x002DF756+980822]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x006ACC62+2510274]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0069F760+2455744]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x004CEABA+551962]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x004CD916+547446]
    Ordinal0 [0x003D5F3B+1990459]
    Ordinal0 [0x003DA898+2009240]
    Ordinal0 [0x003DA985+2009477]
    Ordinal0 [0x003E3AD1+2046673]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x761FFA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x775F7A7E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x775F7A4E+238]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have tried several times only google doesnt load.
python 3.9.5 is used.
the script loads a random proxy from a proxy.txt file first
then the proxy is used as options in chrome
the chrome tab opens normally too.
i hav tried http, https, socks4, sockks5 all of them.
but none worked.
I think its a problem from selenim
any help would be great.
Thanks.